# Power Tower modulo sequence

Tags: number-theory

A power tower, defined here is $a\uparrow\uparrow n$. ($a\uparrow\uparrow 2=a^a$, $a\uparrow\uparrow 3=a^{a^a}$, $a\uparrow\uparrow 2=a^{a^{a^a}}$, etc...) Is there a base $a$ such that $a\uparrow\uparrow n \pmod{10^{n-1}}$ starting with these terms: $$9, 89, 189, 4189, 54189, 754189, 0754189, 20754189, 120754189, 5120754189,\dots$$

(Related to https://oeis.org/A206636)

Thanks for help on this!

Comment: ??? I understood a^^n but not what you are searching for

Comment: Where does your sequence $\dots5120754189$ come from? Is it generated by a specific function or rule?

Comment: Reverse the digits of (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-303%2B336+%EF%9D%8D%2B89+%CF%80%2B80+log(2))%5E(1%2F3)), a random chosen expression.

Comment: Initial tests show that $9,09,109,4109$ are choices for $a$ that satisfy the first four initial segments of the pattern. If this keeps up the candidates for $a$ will diverge to infinity, so there will not be a solution, although I'm sure there is a way to interpret this as a $10$-adic limit.

Comment: your question is if for every sequence there is a $a$ such that ... ? for most sequences there is no such $a$, so you are asking if there  is a simple test on the sequence, telling if such a $a$ exists ?

Comment: There is a typo in my previous comment - $4109$ should be $2109$.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted working this out for the given sequence by brute force, using the observation that solutions are only determined $\bmod 10^{n-1}$. I found that the sequence
$$a_n=9,09,109,2109,02109,902109,8902109$$
solves increasingly longer initial segments of the pattern (that is, $8902109\uparrow\uparrow n\equiv b_n\pmod{10^{n-1}}$ for $n\le 7$ where $b_n$ is the sequence in the OP), but at this point the pattern ends; there are no solutions that extend $8902109$ and hence no solution exists, not even as a $10$-adic limit.

I'm not very strong on the theory here, so if someone could verify that this is a valid method of proof I'd appreciate it.